# How to use all vCPUs on google cloud with dask

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

There are 16 vCPUs on my vertex AI Jupyter notebook, and I am writing a parallelized script. I wasn't sure if the right approach was to hardcode in parallel processing based on the number of vCPUs (and if so, how to choose nworkers vs nthreads). Should I do this

```
from dask.distributed import Client
num_vcpus = 16
dask_client = Client(threads_per_worker=1, n_workers=nvcpus)
```

or should I use the cloud deployment pipeline as outlined [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/deploying-cloud.html) instead? What degree of parallelization by hand (setting up futures and tasks and partitions and then running `gather`) is required? For context, I don't know what Kubernetes is.